# Gson toJson parameter names ("a", "b" etc)

Tags: android, json, google-play, gson

I'm using Gson to create a JSON String from a list of objects. This string then gets sent to our database. This works perfectly fine on my test device and emulator and it's stored correctly on the database when I run it on the devices from my laptop. Problems arise when I then upload our app to the Play Store: we're getting the strings in the following format stored on our database:

```
[{"a":true,"b":"Schedule 1","c":[true,true,true,true,true,true,true]}]
```

Whereas it's supposed to be something like this:

```
[{"active":true,"scheduleName":"Schedule 1","days":[true,true,true,true,true,true,true]}]
```

This happens for all schedules that get sent to our server.
**Can anyone help with this? Why is this happening?**

Comment: Why weird? Is ProGuard obfuscation enabled for your build?

Comment: To expand on the above-  if you use proguard, you need an exception for any class you use GSON on.  This needs to be recursive-  if class Foo includes a class Bar instance and GSON is used on Foo, Bar needs an exception as well.

Comment: In addition to configure exceptions in the ProGuard configuration, you can also pin JSON field names to their respective fields in the mappings by using `@SerializedName` (it will be more verbose, but ProGuard never affects annotation values (I mean strings, numeric constants and booleans) as far I as I know, but I do believe it's a sign of good code design especially for dedicated DTOs containing all necessary configurations for a particular library like Gson), so even if the class field gets obfuscated from `active` to `a`, its name provided in `@SerializedName` would retain as declared.

Comment: Thanks everyone, this helped a lot! I cannot mark any of your answers as solution since they're comments, but ProGuard was indeed the cause